Where to find out more about escape time fractal made by $z_{n+1}=a^{z_n}$
I was messing around making a very very simple mandelbrot renderer in python, and decided to replace the z = z**2 + c in my code with z = c ** z. This produced an image something like this.
This is a version I made later. $x\in{[-2,0)}$,  $y\in{[-1,1)}$,  the bailout value is set to 2, and the max number of iterations is 100. The pixels are coloured white if they don't reach the bailout value and if they do, their red channel is set to 255 * (itersBeforeBail / MAX_ITERS).
I wanted to find out more about this fractal but came up completely short. I looked at wikipedia's list of fractals and couldn't find anything like it, though it seems that this fractal varies quite a lot depending on the bailout value you choose. For instance, it looks like this when the bailout value is set to 5 and all else is kept the same.
I'm just hoping to be pointed to a wikipedia page or at least the name of this fractal, thanks.

Technically, this isn't $z=z^2+c,$ since the question isn't of finding solutions to that equation - there are only two solutions, of course. The question is about recurrences based on the function $z\mapsto z^2+c$ and, in your $z\mapsto a^z.$

@ThomasAndrews The z = z**2 + c referred specifically to a line in the python code I wrote, where that line reassigns z to be the last z squared + c, hence why I put it in backticks instead of using latex.

You should write math here, not Python. They Python code has nothing to d9 with your question.

Here's a great paper on exponential dynamics: http://math.bu.edu/people/bob/papers/notes.pdf

Too long for a comment: $|z|=2$ as a breakpoint is chosen because it can be proved that if $|z_n|>2$ for some $n$, then the sequence $z_{n+1}^2=z_n^2+c$ and $z_0=0$ diverges. This isn't true when you replace $z^2+c$ with $c^z$, therefore you will see in your picture smooth curves corresponding to your arbitrary choice of cut-off.
I am fairly sure that there is no name for your particular picture. It is a kind of bifurcation locus, but not very interesting mathematically because
(1) the map $z \mapsto z^c$ is not really well-defined everywhere (there is a branch cut along the negative real line); you may want to try with $e^{z+c}$, and you will get a nicer picture
and
(2) you didn't say what your starting point is, but in the case of the Mandelbrot set $z_0=0$ is not chosen randomly: it is special because it is the unique $z$ such that $f'(z)=0$ when $f(z)=z^2+c$.
